# How to add a JMenuBar to a JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtabbedpane, jmenubar

I need to create a `JMenuBar` that will be shown under of `JTabbedPane` named as `shapes`. When I changed tab, menu bar will not be shown in the other tab. You can see what I mean  from images.

I created a menu bar and add it to `JFrame` but that is not I mean. If you did not understand a point let me explain.

```
public class Gui extends JPanel {

    JFrame frame;
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu createShapes, display, help;
    JMenuItem RandomShapes, Rectangle, Circle, Square;

    public void createFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(1000, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setFocusable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(1000, 600);
    }

    public void createMenus() {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        createShapes = new JMenu("CreateShapes");
        menuBar.add(createShapes);
        display = new JMenu("Display");
        menuBar.add(display);
        help = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(help);

        RandomShapes = new JMenuItem("Random Shapes");
        createShapes.add(RandomShapes);
        Rectangle = new JMenuItem("Rectangle");
        createShapes.add(Rectangle);
        Circle = new JMenuItem("Circle");
        createShapes.add(Circle);
        Square = new JMenuItem("Square");
        createShapes.add(Square);

    }


    public Gui() {

        createFrame();
        createMenus();

        frame.add(this);

            //===frames part
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        JPanel gui2 = new JPanel();

        tabbedPane.addTab("Shapes", this);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Images", gui2);
            //===endframespart

    }


}
```

### The other tab image

[image: The other tab image]

### Shapes tab image

[image: Shapes tab image]

Comment: 1. Error: Variable names must begin with a lower case!
2. Error: the "createMenus" method not called anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you cannot set menu bar to JTabbedPane.
You need to add JInternalFrame inside one of the tabs of JTabbedPane, then
you can call setJMenuBar of JInternalFrame.

Here is a simple example:

```
JInternalFrame jInternalFrame = new JInternalFrame();
jMenuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
jMenu1 = new JMenu("Save");
jMenu2 = new JMenu("Open");
jMenuBar.add(jMenu1);
jMenuBar.add(jMenu2);
jInternalFrame.setJMenuBar(jMenuBar);
tabbedPane.addTab("tab3", jInternalFrame);
```

Comment: More elegant solution is replace the JMenubar (which attached to JFrame) when changing the tabs.